# Django Channels 4.0.0 + Docker Redis stops sending messages after some time

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis, django-channels

I am using **Django 4.1.3** + **Channels 4.0.0** and Docker with **Redis:latest** in it. It runs on **Daphne 4.0.0**. Also I have frontend written on React that uses [reconnecting websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reconnecting-websocket) for making undead connection to server. But after some time (I can’t say for sure, but about 1 - 2 days)
frontend stops recieving messages from Channels.

Restarting Redis container fixes this issue as 1 - 2 days as I said.

Here is the *docker-compose.yml*:

```
services:
  ...

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes --replica-read-only no
```

Any thoughts what it could be and and how to fix it?
Ps. thank for your time

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the event loop closing and  redis replica synchronization breaking after an arbitrary amount of time. Channels-redis got updated silently and was causing the issues, after rolling it back everything working again. So my advice would be to if channels-redis version is correct and experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just recently and the Channels git page acknowledged it.  The temporary fix until it is addressed was running version 3.4.1.